# How to change the time format in the Source pane in Premiere?

Tags: premiere

What's the way to set the time format in the Source pane to be displayed as 00:00:00?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on the video in "Source" panel (You'll see a blue rectangle)

[image]

Then click Clip -> Modify -> Timecode...

[image]

Select "Original Timecode" and "Ok"

[image]

That's it.

[image]